# How to tell teamcity agent, which aws account to run terraform to

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, teamcity

I spun up TeamCity into a Kubernetes cluster. I have one deployment for the TeamCity server and one deployment for the TeamCity build agent. When I run Terraform on the TeamCity build agent, it creates resources in the same AWS account as the EC2 instance which is hosting TeamCity Kubernetes cluster.

I would like to run a build, which creates AWS resources in a separate AWS account. My thinking is to assign an AWS access key and secret key to the TeamCity server and pass them to the TeamCity build agent, but I don't know how the work flow is going to be.

Currently, I have declared AWS access key and secret keys as environment variables on the build but they are not getting passed to agent. My build steps only contains 3 lines

```
terraform init
terraform plan
terraform apply -auto-approve
```

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with a very similar situation. When we started using AWS, we did not follow best practice around how our scripts authenticate to AWS.

We created users in each account and exported the access and secret keys into our TeamCity build automation to allow our scripts to run in the context of these accounts.

You will wind up with several users in different accounts and will wind up manually rotating the keys for these users, then updating the access and secret keys in TeamCity everytime you need to rotate the keys.

As the TeamCity build agent servers are EC2 instances, it is best practice in AWS to use roles instead of users in situations like this. From the AWS documentation:

> Applications that run on an Amazon EC2 instance need credentials in
>   order to access other AWS services. To provide credentials to the
>   application in a secure way, use IAM roles. A role is an entity that
>   has its own set of permissions, but that isn't a user or group. Roles
>   also don't have their own permanent set of credentials the way IAM
>   users do. In the case of Amazon EC2, IAM dynamically provides
>   temporary credentials to the EC2 instance, and these credentials are
>   automatically rotated for you.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#use-roles-with-ec2

What you should do in this situation is create a role in each account that has access to create the resources that terraform will build. You will need another role for the TeamCity build agent servers, this role should be able to assume the roles created in each account.

Let's say you have two accounts:

1. AccountA is where you want the build agents to run build resources with terraform.
2. AccountB is the account your build agents are running from.

What you will need is:

1. A role in AccountA with access to create resources.
2. A role in AccountB that grants access for ec2 instances to assume the above role.

The instance profile of the role in AccountB should be assigned to the TeamCity build agent servers. The build agent servers are then able to assume the role in AccountA and run in the context of that account with the permissions they need without the need for hard-coded access and secret keys.

You can repeat this process for as many other accounts as you want to build resources in through Terraform.

You will have to add the following block to the aws provider in your terraform scripts to let terraform know what role to assume:

```
provider "aws" {
assume_role {
role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNTA>:role/<ROLENAME>"
}
}
```

Here is some AWS documentation on how to grant access to an S3 bucket in a different account from an EC2 instance:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-instance-access-bucket/

Another useful documentation page on that covers IAM Roes, EC2 instance profiles & cross account access via Roles is here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html

One last link goes through exactly what you are trying to do:
https://blog.e-zest.com/aws-ec2-assume-role-with-terraform

Comment: Thanks you so much for replying bak, in the 1st instance i am actually using iam roles which is assigned to my pod in which agent is running, so you are saying i should create another agent and also another role which will be assumed for the target aws account? if that is the case then i guess i am not for off, and i dont need to do anything in teamcity as such

Comment: currently with the help of my role which is assigned to pod, correct resources are getting created in aws account, i thought this is because my agent is on the same node of aws account may be thats why, but no, i guess i will have to create a trust policy from another aws account and assign it to my agent? let me know if i am on right direction to achieve this

Comment: You shouldn't need to create another agent. You need another role in the other account and allow the role assigned to the agent to assume the role in the other account. Then you just need to tell the Terraform script which role to assume in order for it to know what account to run in. 
This pages in my answer show how to do with trust policies

Comment: hi, your answer makes perfect sense and i tried the above steps by creating a role in another account and assigned that role to the agent and it did create resources in another account. however here comes the confusion, if i am creating s3 role with required permissions and assigning it to agent, then i shouldnt be assigning this role in terraform provider file because agent has permissions anyway to do stuff, can i assign multiple role to agent? if i have more then 1 target account, does the annotation in k8s support list of roles?/please can you answer both question, last bit im stuck on

Comment: one last question before we can mark the answer, if you could please guide me on how to pass access keys and secret access keys from teamcity to agent running in kubernetes pod, i would like to try that also, exactly how you use to do in your organisation, currently i assigned these as env variables, i just dont know how to pass these values to agent, should it be on command line, or should there be a target variable in pod yaml file which will accept these values

Comment: Not a complete solution, antipattern from a security architecture standpoint

Answer (score 0):

My agent.yml file looks like this when i want to add two annotations for 2 separate accounts

spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: agent-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        iam.amazonaws.com/role: arn:aws:iam::account:role/accoun1-s3-role
        iam.amazonaws.com/role: arn:aws:iam::account:role/account2-pods-s3-role

but as soon as i put two annotation, my sts assume role for pod only shows me second role. and when i run the build from teamcity i get this error
no valid credential sources found for aws provider